# How to add WSHttpBinding to NinjectServiceHostFactory

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, ninject, ninject-extensions

After my **NinjectWebCommon** class has run in **App_start** I then bind my WCF interfaces to services like this:

```
public static void LoadModules(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IAccountService>().To<WCFAccountService>();
}
```

How do I tell the system to accept **WSHttpBinding** calls to **IAccountService** ?

Here's my .svc for reference:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" 
    Service="AAA.AAA.AAA.WCFAccountService" 
    Factory="Ninject.Extensions.Wcf.NinjectServiceHostFactory" %>
```

(Note: I'm using the **Ninject.Extensions.Wcf** and only **BasicHttpBinding** seems to work 'out of the box')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure the service in the web.config like

```
  <service name="AAA.AAA.AAA.WCFAccountService" behaviorConfiguration="AAA.AAA.AAA.WCFAccountServiceBehavior">
    <endpoint name="IAccountService" address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="AAA.AAA.AAA.IAccountService" />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help and wonderful open source product. Your donation of time to it is well appreciated. I'll check it once I get back.